# fwrite() printing total bytes written at the end of file

Tags: php

My question is [essentially this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477132/fwrite-adds-the-number-of-bytes-written-at-the-end-of-ouput), which never received an answer, so I guess this is sort of a bump. When using `fwrite()`, the number of bytes written is appended to the end of the file.

```
$my_file = rand(1, 40).'.csv';
$handle = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/../export_search/'.$my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
fwrite($handle, $csv_export);
fclose($handle);
```

`$csv_export` is simply a string of data for a line in a CSV. A loop runs to append consecutive lines to this string, and then the code above is called. There isn't a byte value at the end of each line - just at the end of the whole file.

Thoughts?

Comment: fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error: so do your first fwrite() for the file capturing the returned value in $var, then a second fwrite() to write the value of $var

Comment: Maybe you can check the `$csv_export` first to make sure there is no byte value. Try to output the variable.

Comment: No, I don't want the bytes to be written to the file, but they currently are. Not sure why.

Comment: Just did a var_dump on it. String with no bytes listed at the end.

Comment: That other question did actually get an answer and the OP kind of acknowledged that the code he posted wasn't enough to reproduce the issue. Your question doesn't feel different. Can you produce a self-contained example that exhibits such issue?

Comment: The suggestion to recreate it led to the issue - the same code didn't produce the error, but the file was being downloaded before I viewed it, and the download code was using echo readfile($file_url) instead of simply readfile($file_url) which was outputting the total bytes. Thanks guys. Should I just delete this question since the problem wasn't actually as described?